# How to set the EOL character in any of the sass implementations?

Tags: windows, sass, eol

In windows, the generated CSS files are `LF` ended. How can I set the EOL to be `CRLF`?

Comment: Hm? What are you asking?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Updated. thanks